# How do Iogin User with OAuth credentials after logout?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I have successfully obtained received an OAuth token, saved it the the DB as a new user, and logged the user in.

If the user logs out either manually, through cookie purge, or some other method, do they just perform the same process again? This is problematic because my server will create a new account for them in this case as if it was their first time.

Is there a different process to log them back in a second time without having to authorize through the same channel? I cannot get the user's refresh token/scopes because they are now anonymous after being logged out.

Comment: where does the OAuth token come from? Your site, or a 3rd party?

Comment: if from 3rd party you need to store an association between the 3rd party user-id and your Django user in the db, so when receiving a new login via OAuth token you can return existing user instead of creating a new one

Comment: Yes, Google OAuth2. Right, but if they go to login, and it uses the same process to authorize, then they will be requested to authorize the credentials again (they will see the authorization screen - seems unnecessary to make them authorize a second time). Is that expected? Is it expected that if they log out, they will have to see the google auth screen again to re-establish with my site? If that's the case, can I just verify that this email already exists and login the user?

Comment: Yes - the user logged out, it's expected that they will have to authenticate again to be logged in again.

Comment: Authenticate on my website, yes. But I'm talking about authorization from the Oauth flow to accept the scopes. They have already done this once and it has been saved. Do they have to do it again if they log out? If they log out, they are then anonymous so I cannot get their saved credentials.

Comment: Generally the client SDK for an OAuth provider will handle this - they log in to their Google account in the client, Google recognises the user already authorised your app and forwards the token back to your app without sending the user through the authorise flow again